what is the difference between "detail" and "detailing"?
I am an English language learner, so please forgive me for some errors in expression.
I am confused about the difference/s in meaning between nouns "detail" and "detailing". These two words look very similar when I search for them in a dictionary. I don't know how to choose between them. I considered whether the fact that one  or corresponds to the present participle might be important, but I couldn't find the answer.
E.g.

I want to learn more (detail or detailing) about  (that event/person/design)
There are so many (detail or detailing) on an experience suit.

And so on.
I don't know how to choose between them.

Hello, lou xiu, and welcome to the EL&U. You may want to ask your question on ELL. And it would also help if you explain your confusing the two terms more in detail and provide some examples of sentences where you don't know how to choose between them.

Detail has lots of meanings that detailing doesn't have. Although both detail and detailing seem to be used in the names of car care businesses, so there may not be much difference in that context, if that is the one you are interested in.

Should your second example be 'There is so much (detail or detailing) on an expensive suit/clock/car.'?

'Detailing' has a far narrower definition:

detailing {noun} [singular form, non-count]:
small decorative features on a building, garment, or work of art.

keystones and other masonry detailing


[ODE courtesy of Google]
(ODE labels this usage [noun], and although the plural is rare and hardly ever used with a numeral, this is probably the best designation. The act of detailing is another, separate sense.)
'Detail' is highly polysemous:

detail {noun}:
1 [non-count]: extended treatment of or [in-depth] attention to particular items

explaining without going into detail
giving careful attention to detail

2: a part of a whole: such as
a [count]: a small and subordinate part [= PARTICULAR]

planned the wedding down to the smallest detail

also: a reproduction of such a part of a work of art
b [count though most often used without a numeral]: a part considered or requiring to be considered separately
from the whole

discussing the details of the building's columns

c [non-count]: the small elements that collectively constitute a work
of art

admire the great detail of his work

d [non-count] [photography]: the small elements of an image
corresponding to those of the subject

strong lighting to achieve clarity of detail

3
a : selection of a person or group for a particular task (as in
military service)
b(1) [count]: the person or group selected

a member of a security detail
police details at the parade

(2) [non-count]: the task to be performed

were assigned to kitchen detail


[Merriam-Webster; amended]
So investigating the details of a building's columns would include inspecting the detailing on the building's columns (as well as determining their age, composition, architect, height ...).
One could argue that definition 2c for detail matches the definition of detailing, but 'detailing' has a more tangible connotation.
